# Problem with loading .RData objects: "file ‘pathway.path.RData’ has magic number '' Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated"

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to load an .RData file downloaded from the github repository https://github.com/VCCRI/SPAGI/tree/master/data.

After having saved the files on my computer if I try to load one of them with

```
load("./data/pathwaypath.RData")
```

I get the error message:

```
 Warning message:
“file ‘pathwaypath.RData’ has magic number ''
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated”

Error in load("./data/pathwaypath.RData"): bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
Traceback:

1. load("./data/pathwaypath.RData")
```

It also does not work with readRDS:

```
readRDS("./data/pathwaypath.RData")
```

throws

```
Error in readRDS("./data/pathwaypath.RData"): unknown input format
Traceback:

1. readRDS("./data/pathwaypath.RData")
```

Browsing through stackoverflow I gained the sense that it might be a problem with the serialization protocol used for creating the .RData object. Would anyone know more about it? Are there any known solutions to this issue?

I am running R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24).

Comment: I downloaded the data to desktop and had no problem to load it with `load("~/Desktop/pathway.path.RData")`

Comment: I think your file name is wrong

Comment: Thank you, I checked that, it wasn't the issue, I changed the file name manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that is working for me on version `3.6.3`:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://github.com/VCCRI/SPAGI/blob/master/data/pathway.path.RData?raw=true",temp)
load(temp)

pathway.path[[1]][1:3]
#[[1]]
#[1] "RTN4R"  "NGFR"   "IRAK1"  "MAP3K7" "IKBKB"  "NFKB1" 
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "RTN4R"  "NGFR"   "IRAK1"  "MAP3K7" "IKBKB"  "FOXO3" 
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "RTN4R" "NGFR"  "MAPK8" "JUN"
```